# kdevelop debugger automatically detaches from a process after a few steps

Tags: debugging, gdb, kdevelop

I am trying to debug a few C++ applications with KDevelop 4.0.1(on KDE 4.4.5 and gdb 7.0.1) on Debian 6.0.6. Irrespective of what part of the code I break into, the debugger detaches automatically after stepping through a few instructions. I didn't find anything on this topic on any forums. I tried a few things below.

1. Debugging using gdb on shell works perfectly fine.
2. Tried debugging multiple applications, but the issue is seen.
3. Reinstalling KDevelop did not help.

Am I missing some configuration that could cause this behavior?
(I am new to kdevelop)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that is related to pretty printing of an uninitialized variable.

Lots of fixes have been applied to KDevelop and gdb, you should consider updating to a more recent version.

Comment: I had a look at some other IDEs and finally settled on Qt Creator.